# How to set mysql database name and password in juju charms?

Tags: juju

I have several EC2 instance running using JUJU tool, I have used mysql using following command `juju deploy mysql`, by default the password is null, so how can I configure database user name and master password of mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no configuration option to change the username and password automatically via Juju, so you have to do it by hand.

According to the [MySQL Charm README](https://jujucharms.com/mysql/):

> Once deployed, you can retrieve the MySQL root user password by logging in to the machine via juju ssh and readin the `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd` file. To log in as root MySQL User at the MySQL console you can issue the following:
>
> ```
> juju ssh mysql/0 mysql -u root -p`sudo cat /var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd`
> ```

Comment: any idea on the current version. Bcos, Now i dont see any mysql folder in lib directory.